# Spring Security 2.0.6 what calls the loadUserByName method of an UserDetailService

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, dao

I'm building a simple Sring MVC app. And now i'm trying to add Spring security. I've added a `customUserDetailsService` that uses a DAO to access a MySql database and get users.

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class CustomUserDetailService implements UserDetailsService {

    @EJB(name = "UserDAOLocal")
    UserDAOLocal dao = null;

    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException {
        System.out.println("Checking if this is invoked")
        UserDetails user = null;
        DBUsers dbUser = dao.findUserName(username);

        user = new User(dbUser.getUserName(), dbUser.getPassword(), true, true, true, true, getAuthorities(dbUser.getAccess()));
        return user;
    }

    private GrantedAuthority[] getAuthorities(Integer access) {

        GrantedAuthority[] authList = new GrantedAuthority[2];

        authList[0] = new GrantedAuthorityImpl("ROLE_USER");
        if (access.compareTo(1) == 0) {
            authList[1] = new GrantedAuthorityImpl(("ROLE_ADMIN"));

        }
        return authList;
    }
}
```

And i've added the `UserDetailsService` to the `Spring-security.xml`.

```
  <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="customUserDetailsService"/>
</security:authentication-manager>

<bean id="customUserDetailsService" class="service.CustomUserDetailService"/>
```

I put `j_spring_security_check` as the action to the login form on the `login.jsp` page.

When i enter a valid username and a password the app always tells it's wrong. What's more is i can't find any evidence that the `customUserDetailsService` is running at anytime. (I used `System.out.println("Checking if this is invoked")` to check on the server).

What invokes the `loadUserByUsername()` method of the `CustomUserDetailsService`? When is it invoked?

How can i configure it?

(All the codes i supplied might be unnecessary :))

EDIT:
Here is the rest of the Spring-Security.xml

```
<security:http auto-config="true">


    <security:intercept-url pattern="/AddEmployee.htm" access="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/FireEmployee.htm" access="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/employees.htm" access="ROLE_USER"/>

    <security:form-login login-page="/login.htm"
authentication-failure-url="/login.htm?error=true"
login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check.htm"
default-target-url="/common.htm"/>

    <security:logout
invalidate-session="true"
logout-success-url="/login.htm"
logout-url="/logout.htm"/>

</security:http>
```

I worked around the problem by editing the authentication provider like this. I decided not use DAO, and user database. and used hard coded users inside the xml file

```
 <security:authentication-provider>
    <security:user-service>
        <security:user name="sam" password="sam123" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER" />
        <security:user name="pam" password="pam123" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
    </security:user-service>
</security:authentication-provider>
```

This works perfectly.

But i would like to know why my customUserDetailService was never used, And learn how to use it correctly.

Comment: You can enable debug logs in your webapp to get lots more info.

Comment: You are building a new application but using an ancient version of Spring Security? Why on earth would you do that? The current version is 3.0.5 http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/reference.html

Comment: @Sean Patrik Floyd 
I was following a tutorial. The tutorial used that version. I tried using the new version. But bumped into some unknown tags problems. So decided to work with the older version instead. Besides i am trying to learn the Spring Security concept. Not the specifics.

Answer (score 2):

Sharing more config. from Spring-security.xml would help(if possible)

Spring security is Designed so that your Authentication provider calls `loadUserByUsername()` method of the `UserDetailsService` which returns userDetails Object.
Process is as follows:

- Task of `Authentication Manager` is to Authenticate the user. So it sends the user name to `Authentication provider`.
- `Authentication Provider` calls `loadUserByUsername()` method and passes user name of type String which returns `userDetails` Object.
- Now this `userDetails` object contains all necessary information for authentication, such as username, password, isEnabled etc.

Now if you want to customize `userDetailsService` for using your `Dao` you can customize it.

This is how your authentication process works.
You can refer this [**link**](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/technical-overview.html#tech-userdetailsservice) for broader understanding.

Comment: Furthermore what is the use of the alias of the authentication manager? At first when I tried to deploy the EAR in the server a deployment error came telling me to add an alias to the authentication Manager.